# PHP, curl, and raw headers

Tags: php, curl

When using the PHP curl functions, is there anyway to see the exact **raw** headers that curl is **sending** to the server?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use [curl_getinfo](http://php.net/curl_getinfo):

Before the call

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
```

After

```
$headers = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't show the body of the cURL request. Does anyone know how to show that? Obviously we pass the body to cURL, but for debugging I would like to see EXACTLY what cURL is sending.

Comment: @ChadwickMeyer I'm looking for the same thing: how to show both the headers and the request body. Doesn't seem to be possible. :-(

Answer (score 9):

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_exec($ch);
var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT));
?>
```

Only available in php 5.1.3
http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

---

You can verify that they are the same by using your console and hitting

curl http://example.com/ -I

or

curl --trace-ascii /file.txt http://example.com/

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, the PHP/CURL binding still lacks proper support for [CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION.html) which is a callback from libcurl that can provide all those details.

That's the primary reason why I recommend people to work out HTTP scripting things with the curl command line tool and its [--trace-ascii](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--trace-ascii) option FIRST, then translate that into a PHP function.

Comment: It looks like you're right, I poked around the latest stable PHP source a bit, and it looks like they **use** CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION to implement their CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT options, but they don't expose a fully featured CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION of their own. Side note: I remember your emails from the php curl mailing list.  I'm amazed you still have the patience to do any kind of PHP related libcurl support :)

Answer (score 2):

be sure to set the `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT` option before making the `curl_getinfo` call

```php
curl_setopt($c, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
```

Comment: @Janek
It should be read as follows: 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

Comment: Janek is correct, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT is the option to set if you want to view the header using curl_getinfo() it is documented here http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php