# View CURL's request headers complete with POST data

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

How can I view the full request headers, including post data, using libcurl in php?

```
    $username = ($_POST['t_user']);
$password = ($_POST['t_pass']);
$message = ($_POST['t_update']);

$url = 'http://www.facebax.com/1/statuses/update.xml';
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "status=$message");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
```

I tried to get the command curl_getinfo data that  was not  I needed
i want to know what information and how send in http://www.facebax.com/1/statuses/update.xml 
i want use that api to my mobile application

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP, curl, and raw headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828935/php-curl-and-raw-headers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use this for information about curl :

```
$f = fopen('request.txt', 'w');
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_STDERR ,$f);
```